# How to send a PDF via email with the contents displayed in table like format?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker

Here is the code I'm using now:

```js
function emailQuestionnaireAsPDF(questionnaireKey) {
  if (app.getActiveUserRoles().indexOf(app.roles.Admins) === -1) {
    throw new Error('You don\'t have permissions to perform this operation');
  }

  var questionnaire = app.models.Questionnaire.getRecord(questionnaireKey);

  if (!questionnaire) {
    throw new Error('Questionnaire was not found');
  }

  var tmpDoc = DocumentApp.create(FILE_NAME + ' ' + Date.now());
  var body = tmpDoc.getBody();
  var title = questionnaire.FirstName + '\'s Questionnaire';
  var fields = app.metadata.models.Questionnaire.fields;

  body.insertParagraph(0, title)
    .setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1)
    .setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

  appendField_(body, fields.FirstName.displayName,
               questionnaire.FirstName);
  appendField_(body, fields.LastName.displayName,
               questionnaire.LastName);
  appendField_(body, fields.LikeIceCream.displayName,
               questionnaire.LikeIceCream);
  appendField_(body, fields.FavoriteMovie.displayName,
               questionnaire.FavoriteMovie);
  appendField_(body, fields.FavoriteColor.displayName,
               questionnaire.FavoriteColor);
  appendField_(body, fields.LuckyNumber.displayName,
               questionnaire.LuckyNumber);

  tmpDoc.saveAndClose();

  var blob = tmpDoc.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

  Drive.Files.remove(tmpDoc.getId());
  pdfFile.setName(FILE_NAME);

  sendEmail_(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), FILE_NAME, pdfFile.getUrl());
}
```

I'm trying to append all fields, from a model related to Questionnaire, to the "pdfFile". How is this done in a way all fields & values associated are pasted to the pdfFile in a table like format?

Comment: I guess you already figured it out but if not, in the app settings you need to enable the Drive Advance Settings.

Comment: I had not. Thank you this worked! I went to settings > App Settings > Advanced Services > Add Service > Drive API.

Comment: I'm trying to append all fields, from a model related to Questionnaire, to "pdfFile". How is this done in a way all fields&values associated are pasted to the pdfFile in a table like format? @Morfinismo Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I don't have much time to work on that right now. I definitely know how to achieve that. I'll work on an answer within the next 24 hours and get back to you. I recommend you to edit your question so it matches the answer I'll post.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I'm still new to Stack-Overflow's formalities but will gladly make any necessary revisions! @Morfinismo

Comment: I appreciate your assistance @Morfinismo. If you need more info from me, please let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, this is what I've done:

1. Created a model called **questionnaire** with the following fields:

   - firstName
   - lastName
   - likeIcecream
   - favoriteMovie
   - favoriteColor
   - luckyNumber

I added a couple of test records. Then on the server script I added two functions. The first one to send email looks like this:

```
function sendEmail(recipient, fileUrl, fileName){

  var pdfBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileUrl).getAs("application/pdf");

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipient,
    subject: "PDF Email Sample",
    htmlBody: "Attached the PDF File",
    attachments: [pdfBlob]
  });  

}
```

The second function to generate the document looks like this:

```
function emailQuestionnaireAsPDF(questionnaireKey){

  if (app.getActiveUserRoles().indexOf(app.roles.Admins) === -1) {
    throw new Error('You don\'t have permissions to perform this operation');
  }

  var questionnaire = app.models.questionnaire.getRecord(questionnaireKey);

  if (!questionnaire) {
    throw new Error('Questionnaire was not found');
  }

  //Start generating the HTML template
  var htmlData = "";
  htmlData += "<h1 style='text-align:center'>" + questionnaire.firstName + "'s Questionnaire </h1><br>"; //Title of the document

  //Create table start tag
  htmlData += "<table style='border:none;'>";

  //Create headers and append to table
  var headers = ["QUESTION", "RESPONSE"];
  var hRowStyle = "background-color:#efefef"; //style for table header row
  var hCellStyle = "font-weight:bold; padding-top:4px; padding-bottom: 3px; border-bottom:1px solid #bebebe;"; //style for table header cells
  htmlData += "<tr style='"+hRowStyle+"'><td style='"+hCellStyle+"'>" + headers.join("</td><td style='"+hCellStyle+"'>") + "</td></tr>";

  //Define row cell styles
  var tdSytle = "border-bottom: 1px solid #bebebe; border-left:0px; border-right:0px; padding-top:7px; padding-bottom: 6px;";

  //Create table rows
  var rows = [];
  rows.push(["First Name:", questionnaire.firstName]); // Add firstName
  rows.push(["Last Name:", questionnaire.lastName]); // Add lastName
  rows.push(["Likes Icecream:", questionnaire.likeIcecream]); // Add likeIceacream
  rows.push(["Favorite Movie:", questionnaire.favoriteMovie]); // Add favoriteMovie
  rows.push(["Favorite Color:", questionnaire.favoriteColor]); // Add favoriteColor
  rows.push(["Lucky Number:", questionnaire.luckyNumber]); // Add luckyNumber

  //Append rows to table
  rows.forEach(function(row){
     htmlData += "<tr><td style='"+tdSytle+"'>" + row.join("</td><td style='"+tdSytle+"'>") + "</td><tr>";
  });

  //Create table end tag
  htmlData += "</table>";

  //Create gooleDriveDoc
  var fileName = questionnaire.firstName + "'s Questionnaire";
  var data = Utilities.newBlob("").setDataFromString(htmlData).setContentType("text/html");
  var drvFile = Drive.Files.insert({title: fileName}, data, {convert: true});

  //Mail PDF File
  var recipient = "email@test.com";
  var fileUrl = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/"+drvFile.id+"/export?format=pdf&access_token="+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();  
  sendEmail(recipient, fileUrl, fileName);

}
```

So, in summary, I've created a google document from an HTML template. Then, I used the download url with an access token to fetch the pdf Blob and attach it to the email.

The result is the following:

[image]
[image]

Reading through the code you should be able to catch what it's being done in detail and of course, you can improve it!

References:

- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob
- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken
- https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get
- https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/